# A sufficient condition for the existence of an improper integral (or a counterexample for it)

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Let me try to explain the spirit of the question.

The functions $f(x)=1/x^{p}$ for $0<p<1$ and $f(x)=\ln x$ have the following properties: they are in some respect 'nice' on $\mathbb{R}^{+}$, but diverge at zero. Nevertheless, their improper Riemann integral $\int_{0}^{1}\,f(x)\,dx$ exists. The reason is, one may say, that they diverge 'sufficiently slowly' at the origin.

One might conjecture that the following: if $xf(x) \to 0$ as $x\to 0^{+}$, and $0$ is the only singularity of $f$ on $[0,\,1]$, then $\int_{0}^{1}\,f(x)\,dx$ exists as either a proper or an improper Riemann integral. We may assume that $\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\,f(x)\,dx$ exists as a proper integral for all $0<\epsilon<1$.

I very much doubt this conjecture is correct (because I expect I would have seen it somewhere by now), but have been unable to come up with a counterexample. For instance, no member of the following family is a counterexample: $f(x)=1/x^{p}(-\ln x/2)^{b}$, where $b$ is any real number and $p$ is as above (actually, to make it work for any $b$, the upper bound of the integral should be reduced from 1 to some number between $0$ and $1$---say to $\int_{0}^{1/2}$).

Thus my question: **is this conjecture  correct, or is there a counterexample?**

I haven't carefully defined my class of functions because that delineation is, in fact, a part of the question. I imagine one would want to demand that some property (or a laundry list of properties) hold for $f$ on each closed interval $[a,\,1]$ for all $0<a<1$. And I would imagine that the only property that should really matter is that $f$ be (properly) Riemann integrable on all such intervals.

But maybe other conditions need to be applied in order to say something sensible. I would be OK, for example, with stipulating that $f$ can be analytically continued to the complex plane, and that, except for the singularity at the origin, it is then analytic on an open set that contains the closed disk of radius 1 centered at the origin. As far as the singularity at the origin, however, as indicated by my prototypical examples $1/x^{p}$ and $\ln x$, I would want to allow it to be as exotic as it wants to be---as long as $xf(x) \to 0$ as $x\to 0^{+}$. I would be surprised if, once we are in the complex plane, there is some trickery about this limit only existing along the positive real line but not in general, but I could live with it if that turns out to be the case.

Comment: By "have the improper integral" I suspect you mean that the indicated integral is either proper or improper and convergent.  Perhaps it could be stated more clearly in the form "if $xf(x) \to 0$ as $x\to 0^+$, then...".

Comment: "One might conjecture that the following is a sufficient condition" You mean a necessary condition, right?

Comment: That $xf(x) \to 0$ is not necessary is seen with the counterexample $f(x) = \frac1{x} \sin \frac1{x}$.  It is also not sufficient.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for that! I've rephrased the question.

Comment: @zhw No, I mean sufficient. I've rephrased the question to make this clearer.

Comment: @RRL Thanks for that counterexample to the claim of necessity. Could you explain a bit more why it's not sufficient, either? I'm not surprised at all that it isn't, but is there e.g. a counterexample?

Comment: I think $f(x)=\frac{1}{e^x-1}-\frac{1}{x}$ is a valid counterexample to your claim. Note $xf(x)\to 0$ as $x \to 0^+$ but the improper integral is divergent on $0$ to $1$. I think $0$ is the only singularity of $f(x)$.

Comment: @linguisticturn:  The comment from btilly provides the standard counterexample for sufficiency. The function $f(x) = 1/(x \log x)$ is not integrable even though in this case $xf(x) \to 0.$ My example or the construction in the other answer shows the condition is not necessary.

Comment: @LoveTooNap29 Your function approaches a finite limit (-1/2) at the origin, and the improper integral does exist: $\int \left(\frac{1}{e^{x}-1}-\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx=-x+\ln \left(e^{x}-1\right)-\ln x$, and this, as $x\to 0^{+}$, approaches zero. Indeed, $\int_{0}^{1} \left(\frac{1}{e^{x}-1}-\frac{1}{x}\right)\,dx=\ln(e-1)-1$.

Comment: @RRL Darn, how did I miss $1/(x\ln x)$... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is positive and decreasing on $(0,1)$ and $\int_0^1 f < \infty,$ then yes, we must have $f(x)/x \to 0.$ But in general, no, there are examples where $f(x)/x \not \to 0.$ Here's a sketch of one: Over the points $1/n,$ put a triangular spike of height $n$ and base less than $1/n^3.$ The bases can be chosen to disjoint. Now define $f(x)$ to be one of the spikes whenever $x$ lies in one of the bases, with $f=0$ elsewhere. Because the sums of the areas of all these triangles is finite, we have $\int_0^1f<\infty.$ But $f(1/n)/(1/n) = 1$ for all $n.$

Comment: You can make a partial converse of that statement.  If $F = o(1/x)$ is positive and decreasing on $(0, 1)$ then there exists an $f$ which is not $o(F)$ and whose indefinite integral is finite.  So $o(1/x)$ is the tightest necessary upper bound on an integrable decreasing positive function.  The bound is not sufficient, $\frac{1}{x \log(x)}$ is not integrable, but no tighter bound is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for that. However, was asking about proving or disproving the statement that $xf(x)\to 0$ implies that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$ exists at least as an improper integral. Also, in your answer, surely you always meant to multiply by $x$ and $1/n$, not divide?

Comment: @btilly Thanks for bringing up the function $1/(x\ln x)$---that's indeed a counterexample to my conjecture!

Answer (score 1):

The conjecture (as I suspected) isn't true, and here is a counterexample (with thanks to btilly and RRL):
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{1}{x\ln x}\,.
\end{equation}
Indeed, $xf(x)=\frac{1}{\ln x}\to 0$ as $x\to 0^{+}$, and yet,
\begin{equation}
\int_{\epsilon}^{1/2}\frac{1}{x\ln x}\,dx=\ln\left(\frac{\ln 1/2}{\ln \epsilon}\right)\,,
\end{equation}
which diverges as $\epsilon\to 0^{+}$.